# Como resuelvo este problema en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

me encuentro con un problema en Wordpress, le estoy realizando una web a una casa turística, y ellos necesitan un formulario de listing donde la gente se puede comunicar, y un mensaje automatizado de hostaway les llega para proporcionar mas datos, esta automatización ya esta incluida en varios servicios como airbnb, y en teoría, debería poder visualizarse de wordpress también, hay un plugin de hostaway que descargue del siguiente link [github hostaway](https://github.com/Hostaway/wordpress-plugin/releases) pero realmente no se porque lanza este error, los del soporte de hostaway no han sabido ayudarme, me dijeron que actualizara la versión de wordpress y que también se cambie la versión del php a 7.4, wordpress ya estaba actualizado, y cuando cambié el php el error se puso mucho mas corto, pero sigue igual, y como yo hago paginas en elementor sin codigo, no tengo idea del porque del problema, asi que necesitaría ayuda con esto ya que no es mi area de especialidad, gracias. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por el mensaje de error y revisando el mismo plugin parece ser que no tienes elementos en "Bed Types". Si tienes alguna opción en tu sitio para incluir este tipo de elementos agrega unos cuantos para probar.
El código está tratando de hacer una iteración en elementos que no existen de ahí el error.